# Use of go routines in a Go server

Tags: go, concurrency, httpserver

I need to write a simple web server in Go. It accepts requests, maps the request to avro object and sends it to Kafka. The requirement is that it answers immediately to keep the latency low for the users. Mapping to avro object and sending to Kafka can happen asynchronously. I came up with the following design, but I wonder if it is using Go structures in the intended way or if it can be optimized using channels for example. I'm omitting private methods and initializing structures. The problem is that the server can handle up to 10500 requests a second and then the response time goes up dramatically. So I was wondering if there is a way to optimize it.

```
func main() {
 runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU()) // not needed in Go 1.5.0
 server := &Server{
    Producer: newProducer(brokerList),
 }
 defer func() {
    if err := server.Close(); err != nil {
        Error.Println("Failed to close server", err)
    }
  }()
  Error.Fatal(server.Run(*addr))
}

func (s *Server) Run(addr string) error {
  httpServer := &http.Server{
    Addr:    addr,
    Handler: s.Handler(),
  }
  return httpServer.ListenAndServe()
}

func (s *Server) Handler() http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer r.Body.Close()
    req, err := ParseRequest(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        Warning.Println("Failed to parse request", err.Error())
    } else {
        go handleRequest(s, req)
    }
    w.WriteHeader(204) // respond with 'no bid'
  )
}

func handleRequest(s *Server, req *openrtb.BidRequest) {
  req.Validate()
  var avroObject, err = createAvro(req)
  if err != nil {
        Warning.Printf(err.Error())
  }
  if avroObject != nil {
    sendToKafka(avroObject, s)
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your response is always http 204 even your avro serialization or kafka transport fails but I think this is not a concern in your case. In terms of concurrency, your way of doing it is completely legit and more importantly simple.

Comment: @Gladmir It is intended that the response is always 204.

Comment: 10K is generally acceptable :) Would you mind sharing your cpu/mem stats around 10K traffic? Also, consider these steps; a) For every http request, a new tcp socket is being created, this is cpu/mem intensive. b) Both parsing from the body and serialization are also cpu/mem intensive c) Your kafka endpoint is also streaming based (I hope) but its most probably pooled. So you have 3 choke points you need to focus on. Edit: You need profiling :)

Comment: Cpu / mem stats: 8 cores, 32GB.

Comment: HTTP handlers do not need to close the request body. Because HTTP handlers run in a per-connection goroutine, starting a new goroutine in handler may not provide a benefit.